# How to disable tab panel navigation in sencha touch

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am displaying a tab panel with four tabs in my application, with the first tab displaying by default.

Whenever the user selects one of the other three tabs, I need to check whether the user is already logged in or not by checking the local storage user token variable.

If I do not get a valid value from the local storage user token variable, or the user didn't log in yet, then I have to ask the user to log in by displaying an Overlays page over the tabpanel.

I designed the overlay panel ([example of overlay](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/overlays)) such that when user selects another tab and hasn't logged in yet, then I am showing the overlay login panel.

My problem is that when user selects another tab, the selected tab screen is enabled and that screen appears under the overlay login screen. **How can I disable tab navigation so that when the user hasn't logged in, they can't see other tab screens and they can see only the first tab screen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a example code snippet to solve your problem:

You can handle such things from your `Controller` :

```
Ext.define('MyTest.controller.Home',{
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',  

    config : {
        refs : {
            tabHome     : "#mainView tab[iconCls=home]",
            tabProduct  : "#mainView tab[iconCls=products]",

        },
        control : {
            tabHome : {
                tap : 'showHome'
            },

            tabProduct : {
                tap : 'showProduct'
            },

        }
    },

    showHome : function () {
        if(getLoginState() == true){
            Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().getAt(1).setActiveItem('homeView');
        }
        else{
            Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().getAt(0).setActiveItem('dashboardView');
            showLoginOverlay();
        }
    },

    showProduct : function () {
        if(getLoginState() == true){
            Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().getAt(2).setActiveItem('productView');
        }
        else{
            Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().getAt(0).setActiveItem('dashboardView');
            showLoginOverlay();
        }
    },

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: mainView is the id of the tabpanel ?

Comment: homeView and dashboardView are xtype ?

Comment: `mainView` is `class` which is extended by `Ext.tab.Panel` means that is `tabPanel` , `homeView` and `dashboardView` are `ids` of the `view class`.

Comment: Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().getAt(0).setActiveItem('firstTabScreen') is worked for me, that is first Tab Screen is appearing in user selected tab screen,but i don't want user to see selected tab (tab panel giu shows the correct selected tab by creating 3d box around that tab icon)  is second tab and diaplaying first tab screen.

Comment: @Viswa sorry but not getting you what exact problem is.

Comment: when ever user selects one of the 4 tab in tab panel, i want to show selected tab is first tab by making first tab icon select (because they didn't logged in yet).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22033/discussion-between-viswa-and-pratik-sharma)

Comment: still didn't get it ? sorry, its kind of hard to explain by words

Comment: @Viswa I will be back in 1 hour. We had a lunch break now . Hope you understand. :)

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?252775-tab-panel-and-my-login-overlay-panel-(I-need-solution-for-this-situation)

Comment: @Viswa that's great to hear. Keep it up dude. :)